# sony ericsson websdk question

Tags: mobile

i've read about the sony ericsson websdk and was wondering - anyone who has experience with it? is it good/powerful/fast? 
building own apps using javascript + css sounds great.

is it possible to use jquery with it?

does the websdk run only on eg. android driven xperia x10 or any android cellphone?

or should i better go for the j2me sdk?

thx

Comment: Isn't sony ericsson on Symbian OS ?

Comment: Also, I'd like to know what the difference is with the Sony Ericsson WebSDK and the PhoneGap system? I heard that Sony altered the PhoneGap to make their WebSDK, but I don't know more. I mean, should one use the Sony Ericsson WebSDK instead of the PhoneGap because it's better? Can I use it to make Samsung Android device apps too? Also, check this out: http://androidandme.com/2009/12/news/using-phonegap-and-the-sony-ericsson-websdk-to-develop-android-apps/?awesm=26LNs&utm_medium=awe.sm-facebook&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_content=site-basic

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use jQuery with it?

Yes, but you may want to consider [Zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com/) instead of jQuery because it's jQuery-like but uses less space and is geared more for webkit-based devices like Android and Apple iOS devices. I mean, jQuery is geared more for handling browsers even as old as IE5 I think, and so there's bulk in there that Zepto.js doesn't have to deal with. However, if you really want to use jQuery, nothing will stop you in the PhoneGap environment.

> Does the websdk run only on Android driven Xperia X10 or any Android cellphone?

Unlike my earlier comment above (a comment on your question), I found the answer [here](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Sony-Ericsson-Announces-WebSDK-for-Android-and-Symbian-127400.shtml). Basically what they are giving you in the Sony/Ericsson WebSDK is PhoneGap + an Xperia emulator + a packager for Sony's sales channels for your apps. So, really you might be better off with PhoneGap + emulators for some of the key phones you are targeting. (However, if deploying to Android, I really think you'll be safe if you target the Samsung Nexus S or Galaxy Tab. You'll be able to target most Android devices out there.)

> Or should I better go for the j2ME SDK?

Well, if you love Java and have the time to spend doing Java work, then yeah, go with the j2ME SDK. But if you're wanting to stick with web development skills like HTML5, CSS, Javascript (or Zepto or jQuery), HTML5 offline features like client-side storage, and with the key features of most touch-screen Android and Apple iOS devices like accelerometers, vibration, sound, etc -- then using something like PhoneGap or Appcelerator Titanium are for you. But first, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482586/comparison-between-corona-phonegap-titanium) about PhoneGap vs. Appcelerator Titanium.