# iPhone application development using PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, cordova

I am interested to develop iPhone applications Using PhoneGap.

PhoneGap is an Open-source development tool,by Nitobi team using HTML,CSS and JS. The main use of PhoneGap is for making webApps to look like a native iPhone applications.
As i googled, i found the below one, to start the application.

http://building-iphone-apps.labs.oreilly.com/ch07.html

But, I was strucked at creating a new PhoneGap project. I found none of the articles regarding it. I didnot understand how to create a HTML & JS files to include in PhoneGap application & its deployment.

Can anyOne Of you give me, the complete idea about PhoneGap application development for iPhone..

Thank You so much,

Ramya.

Comment: This question is related, but it only compares the various iPhone web technologies frameworks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482586/comparison-between-corona-phonegap-titanium

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Phonegap [wiki](http://phonegap.pbworks.com/) has a good step by step [tutorial](http://phonegap.pbworks.com/Getting+Started+with+PhoneGap+%28iPhone%29) on how to build and create a demo app.  If you are still having problems, the [google group](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap?pli=1) is very active and quiet friendly as well as a relatively active IRC channel (Server: irc.freenode.net, Channel: #phonegap).

Comment: Kris, Thanks for the information. I have gone through your suggestions.In the tutorial, they copied the application from somewhere and tested using PhoneGap. I want to know ,how the  application(Kilo, used in demo) is developed... and phonegap application flow....is it having any server inside its design.Do we have any way to have a look on that?If yes, could you explain, what actually be done at the time of compiling& Debugging.. Can you please help me....

Comment: Don't quite understand what you are asking.  No, for things like Kilo you do not need a server, its all done in HTML and Javascript.  Develop your application in Safari with a text editor (read the entire book you linked to and things will be much clearer).

Comment: Kris, i asked you about phoneGap architecure & flow of execution. i came to know that jQTouch is used with phoneGap for javascript.How we can create html files using PhoneGap? Please, push me out.

Comment: You create your html files as you would for a normal website (using whatever html editor you like).  You then copy them into the www directory in your phonegap application.  Then you build your XCode project.

Comment: Thank you kris, i did it. we use any server-side language either PHP or else..to make web apps.Right?. i knew that for phonegap,  jQTouch can be used to access server-side data using AJAX code. is it required to download jQTouch separately ,after phonegap installation? will the jQTOuch has any API for creating JS files.For Ex: If application is a log-in page,when user enters his account details, it has to check with server. where can i do this using PhoneGap.  Waiting for your suggestions...

Comment: Yes, you can use anything you want for the server side language (we use PHP too).  I would get your application running in Safari first with JQTouch, then test on the mobile browser on Safari, then worry about Phonegap last.  If you want AJAX to work in safari it is a good idea to host your application on the same server your AJAX is coming from.  JQTouch really isn't related to phonegap, it is just one way of making a web application look like a native application.