# Best practices on using phonegap to convert jqtouch application to native iphone app (on itunes store)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, xcode, jqtouch

After googling extensively I cannot find any good resources on the practices / process used in converting, using phonegap, an existing jqtouch app to something suitable to be accepted by apple for the itunes store. Any links or advice are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is kind of vauge, if you are wondering how to technically convert jqTouch application to Phonegap that question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185553/iphone-application-development-using-phonegap) and a [lot](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596805784/) of [other](http://www.phonegap.com/start#ios) [places](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494778/Getting-Started-with-PhoneGap-(iOS)).

If you are wondering what you need to actually get it accepted by Apple, well that is sort of a black art since Apple doesn't always disclose exactly why an App gets accepted or rejected, however the [guidlines](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html) have been posted.  You can look at the Phonegap google group for stories [acceptance and rejection](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/search?group=phonegap&q=app+store+acceptance&qt_g=Search+this+group).  Basically the main thing for Phonegap projects is that they do something that can't be done on a plain web page (use some feature that Phonegap exposes that Safari does not), or at least appear to do this.  Also though the data can be dynamic, the javascript should not be (at least a majority of it, Google maps may or may not be an exception to this but if you can host the Google Api's on the phone).