# What are the advantages and disadvantages of using Phonegap and Titanium?

Tags: android, cordova, cross-platform, titanium

I am planning to create a cross platform application which works in Android, iPhone and Blackberry? I thought of using Phonegap or Titanium. My questions are as these:

- *Whether in cross platform if it is possible to
  achieve all the native behavior of
  all phone models, something like in Android menu and iPhone gestures?*
- *Apart from cross-platform
  advantage, what are other
  advantage do it have?*
- *What are the disadvantages? Is
  there any limitation when it comes to comparing to
  native app?*
- *Whether I can use same code
  without any modification in all the devices or i have to
  change the code with respective to
  device identified dynamically?*

Comment: this topic has plenty of responses in StackOverflow already; I would suggest a simple search of the forum for a good overview. Then if you have a more specific question post that

Comment: @Aaron Saunders: Thank You.i think i am poor in searching in SO.i couldn't get answers releated to these particular questions!could u please post any link if possible.most of the topic is not exactly releated to these questions in SO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparison between Corona, Phonegap, Titanium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482586/comparison-between-corona-phonegap-titanium)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27686850/88907

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Previous discussion on Stackoverflow: 
[Comparison between Corona, Phonegap, Titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482586/comparison-between-corona-phonegap-titanium)

A good clear explanation from Jonathan Stark: 
http://jonathanstark.com/blog/2010/04/05/phonegap-vs-titanium-mobile-et-al/

In terms of your questions:

To check which native features are available for each framework you will need to check the API docs of each of the frameworks:
The phonegap ones are here http://docs.phonegap.com/

The advantages/disadvantages I think are covered in the two links above.

It will depend what you are doing but I imagine you will have some differences in your code for each platform.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 6):

Following are the answers to your question, hope this will help some one.

> Whether in cross platform if it is possible to achieve all the native
>   behavior of all phone models, something like in Android menu and
>   iPhone gestures?

No it will not supprot all the native featrues using Phonegap the look and feel remains like web.  If you go for titaniam (I have done for one project) some features we need to write cusotm native code to achieve it.  If you are doing this you have to do for both platforms iPhone an Android.  Also the Titaniam will generate a lot of native code.  So, my suggestion is either go to Native or go to Phonegap.

> Apart from cross-platform advantage, what are other advantage do it
>   have?

Apart from cross-platfrom the main advantage is the custom controls, for example if you are doing a custom tab bar that looks different than the native it will be hard to do in native you have to write more code for that.  In Phonegap as it is web you an do what you want.

> What are the disadvantages? Is there any limitation when it comes to
>   comparing to native app?

As I told before,  the UI will look like a web UI and some important features cannot be achieved.  See this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084496/limitations-of-cordova-phonegap) for more information

> Whether I can use same code without any modification in all the
>   devices or i have to change the code with respective to device
>   identified dynamically?

Yes you can do, but I have not done this yet.  See this [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_device_device.md.html) some code change should be done with respect to the device type.

I hope this will help some one