# Learn Android and other native platforms or learn Titanium?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, windows-phone, titanium

I want to make commercial applications for mobile. Haven't done any mobile development yet. So is it better to learn individual platforms like Android, Windows and iOS or it is better to learn Titanium or PhoneGap!?

Comment: this is not a coding question and is of broad spectrum.

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228099/should-i-learn-native-ios-development-objective-c-or-perfect-my-knowledge-in-j?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27686850/88907

Comment: Thanks for the link adnan chiknay. It was a good read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to learn Native platform first like Android , IOS or Windows. Native apps are more reliable , faster and scalable then PhoneGap or Titaninum. Native applications are easy to learn also.

If you wish to learn all the things  you should try learning Native platform first , once you are clear with the idea how things are working you can easily achieve the same in PhoneGap without any or minimum difficulty.

All the best to your learning !!!