# Limitation on mobile cross platform development

Tags: iphone, android, cross-platform, mobile-phones

Currently, I plan to port a Java desktop application, to the Android platform. Besides official [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), I also take a look on, as it will be a plus, if it is able to run in iphone with minimal effort.

- http://www.rhomobile.com/
- http://www.phonegap.com/
- [appcelerator.com](http://appcelerator.com)

Those cross platform frameworks seem nice. However, I was wondering, what are the limitation on those frameworks?

1. Will they still have the same look and feel as native Android application? (Or a native iPhone application)
2. Is there any difference in the speed and responsiveness of the application?
3. Are they able to provide same set of GUI components as in Android SDK? (Or iphone's)
4. Limitation access to I/O, network resource, hardware?
5. Ability to use threading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience (my background being native mobile app development), we get a lot more control with native apps vs framework based apps. That advantage has greatly reduced in android and iphone platforms, however there are a few other things to condsider:

1. If it is a one off app then you are
   better off working with the
   frameworks you mentioned, they
   provide all the features you asked
   about and for a beginner, are a bit
   faster to develop.
2. If you are going to do multiple apps
   then it makes sense to have a custom
   framework for your needs. In this
   case you can reuse parts of your
   Java desktop app and absorb them
   into your framework. You will
   probably need to create iphone and
   android/java versions.
3. If you create your own framework,
   you can also incorporate other
   software development best practices
   like CI more easily when compared to
   off the shelf frameworks.
4. The UI components are different for
   Android and iphone and you are
   better off having them different as
   they have quite different
   sensibilities and interaction. So it
   may not be a good idea to aim for
   one to one mapping.
5. Speed, performance etc are not an
   issue, same for threads support.

Hope these points help in your decision making process.

Answer (score 1):

This post will be immensely useful for you :)

[Comparison between Corona, Phonegap, Titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482586/comparison-between-corona-phonegap-titanium)

As for threading - since both PhoneGap and Titanium (I cannot speak to RhoMobile) allow you to hook into native code from JavaScript (and the reverse) I see no reason why you cannot multi-thread an application using one of these technologies.

Comment: But I want to compare native app (Using compiled language Objective-C or Java) with those cross platform (Using HTML, JavaScript)

Comment: The comparison is going to depend entirely on the applications. Some applications will perform better as native, some may even perform better as html / js applications and for some the differences will be small enough that it won't matter. As for functionality - these tools allow you to hook into native code from JS so you're not really limited there. The real draw here is being able to build your app once and deploy to multiple devices. If this is not a need of yours then native is always better.