# How to create javascript interface for ios application obj-c?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, interface

does anyone know how to create a javascript interface in iOS that can be called from javascript? My aim is to save data from a website in a native fashion and not using html5 local storage.

Comment: What do you mean "javascript interface in iOS that can be called by javascript?" Take a look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675476/can-i-write-ios-cocoa-apps-in-javascript

Comment: Do you mean you have a web view inside your app and want to save data from a website called within that view?

Comment: any progress so far? I'm interested in an optimal solution too, I might need to do it in future...

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, what you need is a mobile webapp packaging solution.

The most popular here is, perhaps, [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/), it supports many platforms including iOS. The product is free and open source. You will still need to use Apple's iOS platform SDK and have a developer account. As for storage mechanism, I believe PhoneGap has a solution for it (allowing the storage to be persistent, not cleared out like browsers' localStorage).

If you want to simplify your deployment process, you may want to check out [appMobi](http://www.appmobi.com/), they build on top of PhoneGap, providing their own development kit and cloud deployment services.

Also refer to this thread that discusses different kits:
[Comparison between Corona, Phonegap, Titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482586/comparison-between-corona-phonegap-titanium)

UPD. Have you tried the [PhoneGap SQLite plugin](https://github.com/davibe/Phonegap-SQLitePlugin) for storage?

Comment: thanks Dmitry, i'm familiar with Phonegap and what I'm looking for is very similar to Phonegap plug-in. I want to store one value from a website and then save it locally in the SQLite DB. I want to create the function that stores the value in obj-c, than wrap it with some sort of an interface and call it from the website.