# Questions on Cross platform mobile app development

Tags: iphone, android, cordova, titanium

I have the following queries on using phonegap / Titanium appcelarator for our cross platform mobile development

Currently we want to develop iPhone compatible and android compatible app with single source code using the cross platform mobile SDKs

Can this phoneGap or Titanium appcelarator works with single source code on both the iPhone and Android platforms?

also is there any other platform works as such?

And how these application will be relased with Appstore / Android market place since they have single code base ( source code ).

Any helps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482586/comparison-between-corona-phonegap-titanium

Answer (score 1):

I have tried out [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) with [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) and also [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/).

Sencha touch is pretty easy as it is based on javascript and can be used with android and iphone. The app created with Sencha touch can later be wrapped inside phone gap and submitted to the appstore.

Titanium again uses javascript but they do some processing on it. So the app is native.
  They do have some common api's that can be used for both iphone and android. But for some advanced features they have 2 seperate sets of api's for both android and iphone.

So both have some differences. And they are both acceptable in Appstore and android market place.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried Titanium, but one of my friends is using [Corona](http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/). He said its support Android and iPhone, and easily port over. You will need at least, adjust the image size, AFAIK, the image size for iphone and androids(various size) are different.

Corona: Write once, build to both iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

corona concentrates on games. it uses lua. if you want to build a cross platform application you should first design your application cross platform. android and ios are different os with different style guides. 
i have experiences with titanium and it worked fine. but i experienced that a cross platform design is important since the most time of building the app was used for programming the user interface. so invest time in building a good mvc design and ui. after that it worked out easily.

Answer (score 0):

Find answers for you question below.

**Can this phoneGap or Titanium appcelarator works with single source code on both the iPhone and Android platforms?**

> > **Yes It can definitely work with single code base. in addition to this you can develop universal App that can run in tablet and handheld from single code base**
>
> (**NOTE:** however on some point you have to differentiate between iOS and Android as some of the functionalities are specific to iOS or Android System. Titanium provide constants to check between iOS and android. It also provides constants to differentiate between Tablet and Handheld devices)

**also is there any other platform works as such?**

> **Other than Android and iOS titanium provides support for blackberry and mobile web platforms also.**

**And how these application will be relased with Appstore / Android market place since they have single code base ( source code ).**

> **You can build App for required platform from titanium it self.**