# Is it possible to accept payment in all currency in my android app using google checkout?

Tags: android, integration, payment

I am trying to integrate payment gateway in my android app.
Purpose of app is to buy online e books.
Site is already Developed and it is using EBS service for payment.
To be specific App is designed for Asian countries only.
Can anyone help me regarding this?
Do i need to simply call my site URL for this or it is not a practical approach.
Any help would  make work my simpler as i am not familiar with this stuff.
Please help me if you have experience with it but please do not just copy paste links as i have gone through many sites for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here, EBS support](https://support.ebs.in/app/index.php?/default_import/Knowledgebase/List/Index/10/integration-kits) you can find the API that EBS provides. There is no specific API currently available for android. I think you should have to implement it at your server side and make a call with web services.

Comment: @mayurbhagat: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482586/comparison-between-corona-phonegap-titanium