# is Phonegap for Mobile development like Java for Computer development. Can it give me real portability?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, titanium, portability

I was looking for a way to make mobile application which will work on all platforms like IOS, Android, Symbain, Windows Mobile. I hit upon couple of things like Phonegap, titanium, it seems that they work on atleat IOS, android. Is this Java of mobile world???

Comment: They seem like HTML/CSS base i was was wondering how can they give me good programming power???

Comment: Please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482586/comparison-between-corona-phonegap-titanium

Answer (score 3):

***Phonegap** basically wraps your code inside a web view and so you code with html,css,js.

***Titanium** on the other side converts your code to the native one, be it for Android or ios.

**Java** on its side is a virtual machine, the code/bytecode stays the same. However if for example you make an app with Titanium for android and for iPhone, they are totally different. So no, it's not JAVA of mobile world.
However as looking from the phonegap side, it comes closer, as you code with web technologies and they are runned in a browser. Just a wrapper needs to be in native code.

Comment: Yes. I say Titanium is for speed, Phonegap is for coding speed. With phonegap you actually do not need to learn anything additional in order to build a web app.

Answer (score 0):

It can give you real portability but it still has its limits.
Specifically you loose a lot of the native abilities that come with the phone.
Phonegap HTML apps will usually run slower than native applications, at least until mobile platforms will have better support for HTML.

Though I would not call it the Java of mobile phones, because unlike Java, it doesn't run on a "virtual machine".

Comment: @Pritesh, the price is: performance and capability. You loose access to native functions except ones provided exceptionally by Phonegap

Answer (score 0):

The Java mantra is "right once, run everywhere" which is similar to the goals of Phonegap - and they both suffer from performance issues because of their portability. So I would say YES.

The other nice thing about Phonegap is that if you have an existing site or wish to make your application available over the internet, for example via a HTML5 manifest file (see www.basecamp.com/mobile), you can.