# Phonegap limitations with Android

Tags: android, cordova

I want to develop one Android/Mobile app that should be support Video play and web services calls.

I am looking for cross platform development, for this whhich framework is better.
I heared Phonegap is best one but i want to know the limitations of phonegap and the performance of App if i select Phonegap.

Please share you Phoneegap vs Native

Can you please share your ideas, that is great help for me.

Thanks
 Vakiti

Answer (score 2):

PhoneGap enables you to build your application for your mobile devices using html5, css3 and javascript. It's easy to get started on any of the seven different platform. Have a look at http://phonegap.com/start for the short tutorial to get started.

There is also a similar question here at stackoverflow you might be interested in reading which compares the different framework that exist: [Comparison between Corona, Phonegap, Titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482586/comparison-between-corona-phonegap-titanium)

There shouldn't be any problem adding video since PhoneGap uses HTML5, so, it supports the video tag [Video tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_video.asp)