# Corona SDK or Appcelerator

Tags: email, frameworks, appcelerator, coronasdk

Which is a better mobile cross-platform development framework - Corona or Appcelerator Titanium?Basically I just want to create a "mail framework" for my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, you should check [this very, very in-depth conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482586/comparison-between-corona-phonegap-titanium) on exactly this subject.

I have never used Corona, but from this conversation I gathered it is mainly for game development.

"The Corona SDK (Ansca Mobile) uses Lua as its coding language. See lua.org for more about Lua.

While we plan to add further web integration and native-UI elements, our focus will tend to be on graphics-intensive applications, such as game development, as opposed to web-based technologies. In other words, we don't envision people writing Corona apps entirely in Javascript/HTML/CSS."

Titanium is much much more useful for UI development as it harnesses the native UI elements  so a "mail framework" seems best suited to Titanium development. [Go ahead and check out the docs for Titanium and see all the native UI elements available for use.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html)