# developing enterprise apps in corona  SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk, mobile-application

Can we develop enterprise applications with corona SDK just like we do in appcelerator? Basically I want to develop non-gaming or web based application for mobile ?Is it possible to create one or do I need to switch to appcelertator for this?

Comment: What is an "enterprise application"?

Comment: Sorry,here it means buisness or non-gaming apps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can. Corona makes it incredibly easy for you to do so. Check out this link: http://www.coronalabs.com/i-want-to-build/business-apps/
Corona offers some of the native Objective-C and Java libraries in its regular SDK, but you can sign up for Corona Enterprise if you need all of the libraries.

Comment: can u give me a non-gaming app developed in corona for buisness purpose like in appcelerator?If its possible please give me comparisions between corona and appcelerator

Comment: [here](http://www.coronalabs.com/resources/case-studies/) are some examples. I don't use Appcelerator, but looking at there website I think it looks like a great solution. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1482586/1369488) is some good information about corona vs appcelerator.