# Best software to use to create an iPad application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, titanium

I was just wondering what would be the best way of going about creating an iPad app. Would it be worth my while learning Objective-C or is Titanium a better option? I have never used Objective-C before but I am familiar with JavaScript. Thanks for any help provided. Also I know there are some C# converters. Has anyone used any of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, objective-C for iPhone development can learn. The IDE is xcode. 
Q & A is related to stackoverflow iPhone objective-C, xcode is a related issue. I recommend to learn objective-C using xcode.

All you have javascript and jquery below to begin developing the framework is available. If the productivity is the difference between objective-c. To the code of a iPhone, Android, Windows Phone, etc. are all reusable.

http://phonegap.com/

http://www.appcelerator.com/ (titanium)

http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/

https://vaadin.com/home

Under the framework of each comparison is post.

[comparison-between-corona-phonegap-titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482586/comparison-between-corona-phonegap-titanium)

[corona-vs-phonegap-vs-titanium/](http://www.prosoxi.com/2011/09/29/corona-vs-phonegap-vs-titanium/)

If you have a skill or ActionScript3.0 using Adobe AIR, iPhone development can be. latest IDE is FlashBuilder 4.6, Flash CS6. To the code of a iPhone, Android. reusable.

[Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/products/air.html)

The following sites include C #-based IDE, you can develop using MonoTouch, but are paid. Easily share code between iOS, Android and Windows Phone 7.

[MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch)

You if you're developing only games, you look at the GameSalad,. Without writing any code development.

[GameSalad](http://gamesalad.com/)

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing small apps that you could envision being "complex webpages", almost any framework like Titanium will be helpful - and might allow you to do it cross platform as well.

If you can envision using hardware or hardware-accelerated features like GPS, camera, or video in the future, just learn Obj-C and go from there. It'll save you a lot of anguish later when you're 80% done with the app and find out that performance is terrible, you need access to a specific feature that your framework does not support, or iOS7 comes out with a cool new thing that you need to use to stay competitive, but can't.

Comment: Thanks Adam this makes allot of sense

Answer (score 1):

As a current C# developer I would recommend biting the bullet and learning Objective-C.  It will only help your career by adding more valuable skills on your resume, and more exposure to other language pros/cons.  There is a lot of information on the web out there to help if you get stuck along the way.