# Is it possible to convert HTML5 apps into native apps for mobile platforms?

Tags: html, mobile

Is it possible to convert HTML5 apps to native apps for mobile platforms? If it's possible, how I can do it?

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Using [**Adobe PhoneGap**](http://phonegap.com/) aka Apache Cordova.

There are other alternatives too. See [Comparison between Corona, Phonegap, Titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482586/comparison-between-corona-phonegap-titanium) for a comparison of different options.

Comment: owh, so do i have to make it in PhoneGap platform, right? thanks for your advice.

Comment: Yeah, checkout PhoneGAp build, if you have na index.html file you should be good to go.

Comment: ok, thank you every one for your kindness to answer.. thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to help. You can upvote and accept an answer if it helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: native apps: are developed using the platform's native language (i.e. Android=java, iOS=swift/objective-c)