# using API's instead of HTML in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I developed a app which has lot of UIWebView displaying HTML data. One of a Sr. app developer suggested me not to use HTML, instead asked me to use API's. Can one let me know how to use it? and any tutorials or suggestions to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Use 3rd Part API which Will be Better For Creating Application.Also Apple will not accept it if its only webviews Bundled as an App ([See the Apple app store Review Guidelines 2.12](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) ). I can Advise you to use any One between Corona, Phonegap And Titanium. If you dont know what is best for you then Have a look at prviously Answered Post: [Comparison between Corona, Phonegap, Titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482586/comparison-between-corona-phonegap-titanium)