# Best Cross-platform development tool for iPhone & Android

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, development-environment

I know that similar questions were asked a lot of times already,
but today when you have so much choice I really need an advice of some one who already have an experience in cross-platform development.

I am planning to develop few applications for Android and iOS.
The applications will have to store data on the device,use calendar,send email,to talk with remote servers.As you see it is nothing special here.

I have found quite long list of platforms :

Corona([Supported Features)](http://www.coronalabs.com/resources/roadmap/)
Moscrif
Icenium
Appcelerator
PhoneGap([Supported Features](http://phonegap.com/about/feature/))
Titanium
e.t.c.

Some of this platform are free and some with subscriptions.
For now I want to try some free and well documented platform that uses HTML5,JavaScript,Java or C#.

I will glad to hear recommendations and opinions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [RhoMobile](http://rhomobile.com/) – This is a solution that uses Ruby, especially loved by Ruby on Rails developers. (Free only for noncommercial applications, prices vary)
- [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/)- – This is a solution that allows you to develop native apps with HTML/Javascript (run through a UIWebView on iPhone) . (Free)
- [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) - Similar to  Appcelerator, I mentioned these two as they seem to have the most vibrant communities, and most extensive support. (Free)
- [WidgetPad](http://widgetpad.com/) are good cross platform development tools. Out of these I would rather prefer Phonegap for iOS and Android Development.

**Edit-** Why I prefer Phonegap

Phonegap is framework to deploy your web based skill to multiple platforms.

Phonegap just executed inside a UIWebView control, and the PhoneGap JavaScript APIs your js calls are routed to native APIs.

**Advantages of Phonegap:**

- Build your app once with web-standards
- Wrap it with PhoneGap
- Deploy to multiple platforms!

Review the link for [Comparison between Corona, Phonegap, Titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1806940/1626878)

Comment: Can you please share with me why you think that PhoneGap is better?

Comment: Is WidgetPad still supported? Or is the project dead?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can's say what is the best. Every one has some pro and contra.
I tested some tools. 
PhoneGap: It's very powerfull and have a large community. PhoneGap is supported by Adobe. 
But the maximum size of local database is limited.

I tested Adobe Air too. For this the user needs the Air runtime. If you use the Adobe flashbuilder you have a nice IDE.

etc.etc.....

I'm courious about the other meanings and tips.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2):

@EvZ, its not the matter of finding best among these cross platform development tools. Each tool has its own strengths to built apps in multiple platforms.

If you want to use these tools you can search in Google and decide which one is better for your application requirement. no one can directly estimate which is good. Basing on your coding skills you can use any one.

For Example: Phonegap is best suitable for the designers. Because it is similar to JavaScript and HTML like that

Comment: I totally agree with you but still it is good to ask for advice from more experienced colleagues.You said that "Phonegap is best suitable for the designers." so which one in your opinion is more suitable for developers?

Comment: i have some experience with Appcelerator, and phonegap. both are simple to use. I don't have any exp with others

Answer (score 2):

I found this http://www.canappi.com/ (I have not tried this). It is looking easy to learn.

rest alternatives you can find [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_application_development).

Comment: Thank you,have you tried one those platform by yourself?If yes which one do you prefer and why?

Comment: I have tried sencha touch and phone gap. They are also easy to learn and good API and documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest PhoneGap :
please see  http://phonegap.com/

Simple! Easy to work with and Free!!