# Unity iOS/Android for httpServer and WebSocketClient

Tags: c#, android, ios, mono

I start using [Unity](http://unity3d.com/).

I understand Unity is based on Mono.net, so I wonder if it's fairly possible to develop apps using .net framework like [Xamarin](https://xamarin.com/%E2%80%8E).

For instance, I am going to develop an app that has a httpServer in the background and webView as the frontend UI. (HybridApp with native code).

In this case, can I simply use [HttpServerClass of .net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httpserver%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)?

Also, I need to implement WebSocketClient and UDP sender/receiver. I know this can be done in C# with .net/mono. Is it fairly possible to implement these with Unity? or some restriction to do that for some reason?

Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249500/xamarin-2-0-vs-appcelerator-titanium-vs-phonegap ?
Not exactly what you're asking, but might be of interest.