# BB native app SDK to support OS 7 and 10

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

We are  in a need to develop the native app which should target both 7 and 10 OS version in BB devices. The app should support webview (load external url in the native app).
By analysing in BB support site, there are native SDKs available for 10 but i could not conculde if there any single SDK that would support both 7 and 10 OS.

http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/java/documentation/introducing_sdk_1968206_11.html
http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/download/

I dont find much details about the best develpment tool to target both the OS.
Please help me
Thanks,
DD

Comment: I think the old WebWorks did, but not sure if still supported.

Comment: You highlighted and @BojanKogoj noted webworks as what they advertise on their site. If you are inclined to go this route, I'd rather use a more established [cross-platform tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249500/xamarin-2-0-vs-appcelerator-titanium-vs-phonegap). Primarily because I don't trust Blackberry to be consistent or to even support their own products. I don't know if I'd consider these tools as native, but its the closest to what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestions ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't develop an App to target both OS7 and BB10 devices.

BlackBerry 10 and BBOS7 are as alike as iOS and BBOS7,  they don't share ANYTHING.  You have to treat them completely different.