# multi-platform mobile application, use phonegap?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, blackberry-10

I am in the first stages of developing a multi-platform mobile application
on (Android,IOS,BlackBerry 10).
**It is a book selling application**
i do not know if i should use phonegap or build the application for the three platforms independently

what do you guys recommend i should use??
and what are the pros and cons for each approach??

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: "Go native or go home". That's my opinion. Someone else will come on and say "Use Phonegap", someone else will then list his/her favourite cross platform library. After that you'll get an answer saying "HTML5+CSS is the best". None and all of them are valid. You'll get a discussion, but not an answer; and SO is not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 2):

If you care about performance I wouldnt recommend building the application in PhoneGap or Titanium or anything similar.

From personal experience:

PhoneGap is very easy to use/learn and can build good looking UIs very fast. The problem is that is really slow compared to other solutions. You basically build with HTML.

Titanium would result in a faster - more responsive application BUT it would require more coding and tuning. Here you basically build with java script. Also, despite the fact that is universal there might be cases where you would have to build separate code for android and for iOS for example to do the same job.

For best user experience I would recommend (and I think many will agree) going native for each platform and trying to keep a consistent UI.

Also since this is not the first question about the mentioned frameworks please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482586/comparison-between-corona-phonegap-titanium) and on many other questions that compare these frameworks.

Comment: I guess you meant: "If you care about performance I wouldn't recommend building the application in PhoneGap or Titanium or anything similar. "