# Embedd HTML5 inside native iOS Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, html, mobile-development

i am searching for a way to extend my native iOS App (written in Objective-C) with HTML5/CSS/JS

So i could write parts of my App´s Code in HTML like a basic shop or similar where code in HTML already exists.

But i don´t want to destroy the great native like look and feel or make users think they left the app and entered a scaled-down version of Safari or similar. So they won´t even feel they are on external HTML on the net.

I want a HTML page inside my App but with full advantages of device like animations, transitions, preloading, no borders. Maybe even make use of device functions like accessing camera, sound and so on.

How could this be done if possible?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use [JavaScriptCore](http://nshipster.com/javascriptcore/) as a bridge between your native app and Javascript logic. You can also use a UIWebView to bridge between your native and web apps using something like [this](https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge).

Answer (score 0):

You could explore UIWebView  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/

Though offhand I am not sure if it supports everything you are hoping for in terms of animation/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your choices are:

- PhoneGap
- Titanium
- UIWebView

More on that here:
[Comparison between Corona, Phonegap, Titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482586/comparison-between-corona-phonegap-titanium)