# Will iOS web wrapper app get rejected?

Tags: ios, responsive-design

I am planning on making a hybrid app. There will be a web mode in wich I will show a SAS responsive app and advanced mode that will take advantage of the native capabilities of the phone. The purpose of this is not to rewrite the web app natively on IOS but reuse the existing web app. The advanced mode is simply for features only available via a mobile device. Will an app like this get rejected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [App Store Review Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html), yes, this kind of app will be rejected.

February 2016 Guidelines, section 2.12:

> **2.12** Apps that are not very useful, are simply web sites bundled as apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected

June 2016 Guidelines, section 4.2:

> **4.2 Minimum Functionality**
>   Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it beyond a repackaged website. If your app is not particularly useful, unique, or “app-like,” it doesn’t belong on the App Store. If your App doesn't provide some sort of lasting entertainment value, or is just plain creepy, it may not be accepted.

However you can reuse your codes by creating cross-platform based apps using some SDK such as: [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) , [Titanium - Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/mobile-app-development-products/)  based on your need and requirement you can go through their documents and choose one.

More details on choosing a better tool can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482586/comparison-between-corona-phonegap-titanium).

Answer (score 1):

I think that if your app is more like a web page than a mobile application then, it will get rejected. Here is a link with common app rejections from apple (https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/rejections/)

From that page:

> **Web clippings, content aggregators, or a collections of links**
>   Your app
>   should be engaging and useful, and make the most of the features
>   unique to iOS. Websites served in an iOS app, web content that is not
>   formatted for iOS, and limited web interactions do not make a quality
>   app.