# including css file to a button in android studio

Tags: android, css

Is it is possible to apply css files in android application? **For example** if I have css file for button, then how can I access that file in my android application if am using android studio?

Comment: are you using `webview` or `PhoneGap` like SDKs?

Comment: No..I dont have any idea that how to access css file.I did not use anything like webview. I have <Button> inside layout.and the functionality for that button is there in .java file.

Answer (score 1):

Android isn't support CSS. Instead android has it's own mechanism, [styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

Or you can use Apps with HTML and CSS in [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) which is packaged in android assets.

Or you can use Frameworks like PhoneGapp,Corona,Titanium.
[Comparison between Corona, Phonegap, Titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482586/comparison-between-corona-phonegap-titanium)

Comment: Ok. Whether I have to change my codes which I used for button click in .java file,if use WebView in android.

Comment: @Amshu, You can put this .css and .html file to assets, and in html draw button and set onclick for webview.